# Learning Java EE, do I need GlassFish or enough with Tomcat HTTPd?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, tomcat7, osx-mountain-lion

I am learning `Java EE`. I am very newbie and I am following old video courses that invite me to install `Tomcat server`.

My question is, do I need to keep using Tomcat? Or install an alternative? Is GlassFish a HTTPd like Tomcat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat is no full fledged application server, it's "just" a servlet container. Use jboss 7 or a recent glassfish and save your energy. There is also TomEE which is basically a tomcat with the required Java EE libs to be web profile compliant.

Comment: Sidenote: If it's an old video course it may be about the outdated J2EE (you don't want to learn that) instead of the modern Java EE.